# Gradient Descent doesn't match with optimal equation

Tags: machine-learning, octave, gradient-descent

[image: Original data (Blue), gradient descent regression (Orange), Optimal Equation (yellow)]
I have a dataset to fit a curve. I used both of Gradient Descent and Optimal Equation. The optimal equation stands for:

```
theta=inverse(transpose(X)*X)*transpose(X)*Y;
```

Now, as it seems in the image, they both doesn't match. I have tried out all possibilities of juggling with learning rate, regularization parameter, they still don't match.

Comment: might not fix your problem but you should be using pseudo-inverse instead of regular inverse in case your matrix cannot be inverted.

Comment: Yes sir, I used that only. I was coding in octave and used pinv instead of inv. Thank you :)